# Handlebars: Calling a helper within a call to another helper?

Tags: handlebars.js

So I have 2 helpers, `#hex` works correctly when used separately, and `#rgb` also works correctly when a color has been passed directly.  However, ideally, I'd like to use my `#hex` helper within the call to the `#rgb` helper but I'm not having much luck.  Here's what I have so far.

**Helper within helper - Doesn't work as expected:**

```
{{#rgb {{#hex color}}{{/hex}} -0.25}}
```

**Example of what is expected of the above:**

```
{{#rgb #abc123 -0.25}}
```

Is this achievable within handlebars or would it be easier if I wrote a new helper that included both my `#rgb` helper and `#hex` helper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with parentheses rather than curly brackets:

```
{{helper1 (helper2 var1) var2}}
```

Example:

```js
// dummy helpers
Handlebars.registerHelper('rgb', function(color, opacity) {
  return color + ' ' + opacity;
});
Handlebars.registerHelper('hex', function(color) {
  return color + 'hexified';
});

// now in template
var template = '{{rgb (hex color) -0.25}}';
Handlebars.compile(template)({color: 'green'});
//Outputs "greenhexified -0.25"
```

[Subexpressions docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions)

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{{outer-helper (inner-helper 'abc') 'def'}}
```